# How to use PortAudio full duplex with different devices without clicks?

Tags: core-audio, resampling, portaudio

We are trying to use a full-duplex stream from two different devices on two different clock domains. PortAudio reports flags periodically, which I've put down to the interfaces being on different clock domains.

I have read and understood the behaviour documented in http://www.portaudio.com/docs/proposals/001-UnderflowOverflowHandling.html, and it is consistent with my observations. These flags are of course accompanied by clicks. I can reproduce this behaviour easily in the pa_fuzz example, so I believe it to be expected behaviour.

What I'm unsure of exactly what I should do with this information? The flags tell me that an overflow/underflow has already happened; how could I feasibly implement any resampling with this?

Am I going about this completely wrong? What is the typical usage pattern for PortAudio  full-duplex using two different devices?

I'm using Core Audio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proper answer for handling it at the PortAudio level, but there is a platform-specific solution that you could consider.

On OS X, you can create an aggregate device that combines the two devices, and enable drift correction to have CoreAudio perform the resampling.  The resulting aggregate will have the inputs and outputs for both devices, so it may take additional logic to select the input and output channels of interest.

You could try it first by creating an aggregate device using `Audio MIDI Setup.app`.  Apple does have some support notes on it, like
[Create an Aggregate Device to combine multiple audio interfaces](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000), and [Set aggregate device settings in Audio MIDI Setup on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/audio-midi-setup/set-aggregate-device-settings-ams094c7edb4/mac) (which may have conflicting guidance on selecting drift correction)

I'm not sure it's formally documented other than headers like `AudioHardware.h`, but it is possible to create an aggregate device programatically as well.  I have only experimented with it myself, and recall having some intermittent issues configuring the device (perhaps an asynchronous behavior with some operations? ).

Of course, if you're using PortAudio and trying to find a portable solution, this won't solve the issue generally.